# Append a string only once in objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to append a string only once when the view appears. Problem is, when I am moving back from previous view, text gets appended repeatedly. because I have kept the string appending code in `viewWillAppear`.

Here is the code,

```
if (!sharedController.perimeterFencesFreeOfHazard) {
    NSString *origText = _messageLabel.text;
    count++;
    _messageLabel.text = [origText stringByAppendingString:@"\n • Perimeter fences & signs"];
    //count++;
}
```

How to ensure string gets appended only once?

Comment: viewwillappear will be called at everytime by the way its coming to the foreground . Put it in **ViewDidLoad**...

Comment: seems your if condition is true every time your view appears,move it to viewDidLoad and change the sharedController.perimeterFencesFreeOfHazard value after adding text.

Comment: Best way to do so is write your code in `viewDidLoad:` method. And there are many alternatives also. 1. You can compare `BOOL` value. 2.`if ([str rangeOfString:@"Perimeter fences & signs"].location == NSNotFound){//append string }else{//already append}`

Answer (score 2):

So you need a *flag*, which tells you if the text has been added for that view or not.

MyViewController.h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    BOOL _textAdded;
}

@end
```

MyViewController.m:

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear {
    if (!sharedController.perimeterFencesFreeOfHazard && !_textAdded) {
        NSString *origText = _messageLabel.text;
        count++;
        _messageLabel.text = [origText stringByAppendingString:@"\n • Perimeter fences & signs"];
        _textAdded = YES;
    }
    ...
}

@end
```

In fact, it looks like you were going down that road with your `count` instance variable, which is just as good.

Comment: `UIView` should be `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Move your code from `viewWillAppear:` to `viewDidLoad:`. As `viewDidLoad:` method is called just once when the view is created.